# How do I activate XSL for PHP5?

Tags: php

It is said here http://www.joomlawebserver.com/booklibrary/booklibrary-1.0.x-free-manuals/19.-php5-extensions-for-booklibrary.html

```
PHP5 includes the XSL extension by default and it can be enabled by adding the argument --with-xsl[=DIR] to your configure line. DIR is the libxslt installation directory.
```

But I don't understand what configure line is about (is it php.ini ?)

Comment: why not do XSL the typical way by just adding a include in the HEAD section of HTML?

Comment: I'm following a tut on symfony and it requires that I do so.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be compiled in when PHP5 is compiled, but it probably is. Adobe has a good article on enabling it (which doesn't apply if you're using a hosted account) and testing for it here: [Configuring and Testing PHP Servers for XSL Support](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/config_php_xslt_07.html) as part of their Dreamweaver support

Comment: +1 because this covers most of the install methods. For linux you should try `apt-get install libxml libxslt` or `yum install libxml libxslt` which is easier than the compile from source method mentioned by Adobe.

Comment: The Adobe link is broken now :-(